# Using bash, how do you get alerts when a file stops being updated?

Tags: bash, watch, filesize

I want to be alerted, say by email, if a file does not change for x minutes.

For context, an application is running 24/7 collecting tweets on an unattended system. If the file storing the tweets doesn't change for x minutes, I need to go and check the application hasn't terminated unexpectedly.

Any ideas please? I considered `watch` but I am new to bash and Linux in general.

Comment: How about find -mmin -5 in a script that runs off a cron job every 5 minutes?

Comment: Consider setting your application as a service, and let systemd restart it if it crashes: https://ma.ttias.be/auto-restart-crashed-service-systemd/ -- that would remove the need to monitor a log file as a measure of your application's health.

Comment: Setting the application as service won't catch the more common problem of the application not crashing but not getting tweets. Eg Twitter often stops sending tweets irrecoverably for a number of reasons (eg rate limits).

Comment: Once upon a time, Twitter published standard RSS feeds. I guess now their closed-source non-standard API is much less solid and break for reasons impossible to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inotifywait`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

MONITOREDFILE=/path/to/monitoredfile

TIMEOUT=600 # 600s or 10 minutes

EMAIL=user@example.com

lastmodified="monitoring started on $(date -R)"
while inotifywait \
  --quiet \
  --timeout $TIMEOUT \
  --event 'MODIFY' \
  "$MONITOREDFILE"
do
  printf '%s has been modified before %s seconds timeout\n' \
  "$MONITOREDFILE" $TIMEOUT
  lastmodified=$(date -R)
done
printf '!!! ALERT !!!\nFile %s has not been modified since %s seconds\n' \
    "$MONITOREDFILE" $TIMEOUT >&2
mailx -s "Stalled file $MONITOREDFILE" "$EMAIL" <<ENDOFMAIL
Monitored file $MONITOREDFILE has not been modified since $lastmodified.
ENDOFMAIL
```

A different approach to get file last modification with GNU `date`, and having the loop empty:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

MONITOREDFILE=/path/to/monitoredfile
TIMEOUT=600 # 600s or 10 minutes
EMAIL=user@example.com

while inotifywait --quiet --timeout $TIMEOUT --event 'MODIFY' "$MONITOREDFILE"
do :;done
lastmodified=$(date --utc --iso-8601=seconds --reference="$MONITOREDFILE")
mailx -s "Stalled file $MONITOREDFILE" "$EMAIL" <<ENDOFMAIL
Monitored file $MONITOREDFILE has not been modified since $lastmodified.
ENDOFMAIL
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this. Wouldn't a cron job be more elegant than a loop?

Comment: The loop only actually run if the file is modified or it times-out. So not much. A Cron job would have to poll file modification. `inotifywait` suspends the script execution and is entirely event driven.

Answer (score 1):

With for example a file named "tweets" in the directory "tmp", we could run a script incorporating find with the mmin flag. We can signify any changes to the file in the last 5 minutes with -5. If the count of the files returned by the find command is not 0 (through piping through to wc -l) we then run the command to email.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$(find /tmp -name "*tweets" -mmin -5 | wc -l)" != "0" ]]
then
     echo "There is an issue" | mailx -s alert someone@someemail.com
fi
```

This can then be set up to run every 5 minutes off a cron job.

Comment: I think you mean `if [[ "$(find /tmp -name "*tweets" -mmin -5 | wc -l)" = "0" ]]` not `!="0"`. Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you say the service is not that critical, you can just create a cronjob to check the modification time of the certain file, and call your alerting script if some condition was satisfied.

If that is the case, google some keywords like "crontab", "find mmin", and build your cronjob.

Otherwise, IMO, a good way could be using something like grafana. There you can define how do you or your team get informed when some event occurred.

Your program needs to somehow register its status. E.g. Prometheus metrics.

In this way, your alert/monitoring is separated from the server your application is running on. Also you can track all the historical status of the service.

Think about if you run a cronjob or shell script on the server to check the file modification timestamp and alert on some event. In case the server is down, you won't get alert, and of course, you think the service is running well.

Again, it all depends on how important is your service.

Comment: grafana is a bit too much on this occasion, but good to know.